# Hot to get max value with where clause with EF5?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have tried every scenario and cannot get this to work.  What is the EF5 syntax to retrieve a maximum field value AND use a where clause at the same time?

This is what I've tried:

```
int result = context.ArchiveItems.Where(x => x.LevelA == levelA && x.LevelB == levelB && x.LevelC == levelC).Max(y => y.LevelCItem);
```

Here's the table.  All of the "Level*" columns exist in a unique constraint.  I need the MAX LevelCItem where the OTHER "Level*" fields exist in a certain combination:

- TABLE "ArchiveItems"
- ItemId bigint PK
- LevelA int
- LevelB int
- LevelC int
- LevelCItem int

I have gotten several errors.  The latest is:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type.

Thanks, in advance, to anyone that can help.

Comment: the fields types you posted are in context of the database engine, I think in the context of c#, it may be `int?` and the value may be missing/null, you should check it again.

Comment: None are the fields are nullable.

Comment: How do you know that? Could you just try looping through all the items and printing them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that the "*materialized value is null*" means that the result collection after applying the `Where` filter is empty and evaluating the maximum of an empty collection's property is not supported by LINQ-to-Entities. (They apparently had some doubt to say that the default should just be `0`.) You can fix the problem by casting to a nullable `int?`:

```
int? result = context.ArchiveItems
    .Where(x => x.LevelA == levelA && x.LevelB == levelB && x.LevelC == levelC)
    .Max(y => (int?)y.LevelCItem);
```

Note that the return type `result` is nullable now. If `result` is `null` it indicates that the filtered collection was empty. If you want to get the value `0` in this case just append `GetValueOrDefault()` at the end of the query:

```
int result = context.ArchiveItems
    .Where(x => x.LevelA == levelA && x.LevelB == levelB && x.LevelC == levelC)
    .Max(y => (int?)y.LevelCItem)
    .GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `LevelCItem` is of type `int?`.

Use:

```
int result = context.ArchiveItems.Where(x => x.LevelA == levelA && x.LevelB == levelB && x.LevelC == levelC).Max(y => y.LevelCItem ?? 0);
```

Comment: Nope.  None of the fields are nullable.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var result = context
.ArchiveItems
.Where(x => x.LevelA == levelA && x.LevelB == levelB && x.LevelC == levelC)
.OrderByDescendig(y => y.LevelCItem)
.Select(y => y.LevelCItem)
.FirstOrDefault();
```